# Select elements without values in ancestors using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to select certain elements in XML for which their ancestors don't have a specific value. For example purposes let's have this XML:

```
<doc>
   <block platform="mobile">
      <xref>1</xref>
   </block>
   <block platform="desktop">
      <xref>2</xref>
   </block>
   <block>
      <xref>3</xref>
   </block>
</doc>
```

I need something that selects all xrefs that don't have "mobile" as their platform value in themselves or any of their ancestors. In the example above the query should return xrefs 2 and 3, as neither them or any of their ancestors have platform set to "mobile" (or don't have platform defined at all).

I tried several combinations of xpath queries using ancestors, trying to concat all platform values for ancestors of xref and using not(contains()) to filter out the mobile part, but all with no luck.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this XPath:

```
//xref[not(ancestor-or-self::*/@platform = 'mobile')]
```

It's generally good to avoid `//` if you can. If your XML is always going to have the structure above, you can instead use:

```
/doc/block/xref[not(ancestor-or-self::*/@platform = 'mobile')]
```

The part between the `[]`s is the same in both.

Comment: From what I can see right now this solves my needs perfectly. I only started learning XPath 2 days ago so I'm trying to wrap my head around what this is doing, but thanks a lot!